# Netbeans code completion for a recordset

Tags: php, sql, netbeans

Having declared a query in PHP and fetched a row

eg

```
$query=$db->query("select name,address from people where postcode like 'SO%'");
$row=$query->fetch_object();
```

is it possible to set up code completion so that when I type

```
$row->
```

I get a dropdown list of the fields in the query (ie name and address). Code completion works well for lots of other things, including inside SQL statements, so I thought this would be a nice feature (I'm hoping someone will tell me it's already there!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$row` is to **design time**, not filled with values. This value is only set at the **Runtime**, with a database query.

Only a workaround if you absolutely want `mydata->` .

The advantage of the function `setProps()`, the values ​​can be validated.

```
[...]
define(val1, "name");
define(val2, "address");

$query = "SELECT ".val1.", ".val2." from people where postcode like 'SO%'";
$result = mysql_query($query);

if (!$result) {
    $message  = 'invalid query: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
    $message .= 'query: ' . $query;
    die($message);
}

while($rows[]=mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC));

class MyArrayObject extends ArrayObject {
        public $name;
        public $address;

        public function setProps($name) {
            if (isset($name[val1])) {$this->name = $name[val1]; }
                               else {$this->name = 'n/a';}
            if (isset($name[val2])) {$this->address = $name[val2]; }
                               else {$this->address = 'n/a';}
        }
}

$mao = new MyArrayObject($rows,ArrayObject::ARRAY_AS_PROPS);
$iterator = $mao->getIterator();
while ($iterator->valid()) {
    $mao->setProps($iterator->current());
    echo  "<br>\n";
    echo $mao->name . "<br>\n" ;
    echo $mao->address ;
    $iterator->next();
}

mysql_close($link);
[...]
```

**code completion**

[image]

Comment: That is ingenious. Thank you.
I take your point about runtime versus design-time, but in theory Netbeans could be programmed to realise that $row is a fetch from the query $query and the SQL for this contains fields name and address and so display them.

Answer (score 1):

There is no any code completion for this.

You only can autocomplete for existng class with vdoc.

```
$query=$db->query("select name,address from people where postcode like 'SO%'");
$row=$query->fetch_object();
/* @var $row \Existing\Class */
$row->
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I suspected as much. Maybe I could try and write a plug in to do it!